# How can I intelligently import multiple pandas data frames from a single .csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, python-3.8

I have a single `.csv` file which contains multiple tables of logged data spanning multiple days like so:

```
ID: 1281        
Location:   NA  
Status: Active          
From    2020-07-13 00:00:00 To  2020-07-14 00:00:00
            
Date/Time   Reading  Low     High
...
2020-07-13 22:25:39 29  10  35
2020-07-13 22:30:56 29  10  35
2020-07-13 22:36:12 29  10  35
2020-07-13 22:41:28 28.5    10  35
2020-07-13 22:46:45 28.5    10  35
2020-07-13 22:52:01 28.5    10  35
2020-07-13 22:57:17 28.5    10  35
2020-07-13 23:02:33 28  10  35
2020-07-13 23:07:50 28  10  35
2020-07-13 23:13:06 28  10  35
...

ID: 1282        
Location:   NA  
Status: Active          
From    2020-07-13 00:00:00 To  2020-07-14 00:00:00
            
Date/Time   Reading  Low     High
...
2020-07-13 22:25:39 30  10  35
2020-07-13 22:30:56 31  10  35
2020-07-13 22:36:12 31  10  35
2020-07-13 22:41:28 29.5    10  35
2020-07-13 22:46:45 30  10  35
2020-07-13 22:52:01 29.5    10  35
2020-07-13 22:57:17 29.5    10  35
2020-07-13 23:02:33 29  10  35
2020-07-13 23:07:50 29  10  35
2020-07-13 23:13:06 29  10  35
...

ID: 1281        
Location:   NA  
Status: Active          
From    2020-07-13 00:00:00 To  2020-07-14 00:00:00
            
Date/Time   Reading  Low     High
...
2020-07-14 22:25:39 29  10  35
2020-07-14 22:30:56 29  10  35
2020-07-14 22:36:12 29  10  35
2020-07-14 22:41:28 28.5    10  35
2020-07-14 22:46:45 28.5    10  35
2020-07-14 22:52:01 28.5    10  35
2020-07-14 22:57:17 28.5    10  35
2020-07-14 23:02:33 28  10  35
2020-07-14 23:07:50 28  10  35
2020-07-14 23:13:06 28  10  35
...

ID: 1282        
Location:   NA  
Status: Active          
From    2020-07-13 00:00:00 To  2020-07-14 00:00:00
            
Date/Time   Reading  Low     High
...
2020-07-14 22:25:39 30  10  35
2020-07-14 22:30:56 31  10  35
2020-07-14 22:36:12 31  10  35
2020-07-14 22:41:28 29.5    10  35
2020-07-14 22:46:45 30  10  35
2020-07-14 22:52:01 29.5    10  35
2020-07-14 22:57:17 29.5    10  35
2020-07-14 23:02:33 29  10  35
2020-07-14 23:07:50 29  10  35
2020-07-14 23:13:06 29  10  35
...
```

Where the headers are "Time", "Reading", "Low" and "High" - apologies if that isn't clear from the above, I can reformat if required.

All tables pertaining to a particular day are grouped together, then grouped again below that for the following day and so on.

This structure is repeated for each ID and each date such that there can be hundreds of tables within a single `.csv`.

There are also 3 unwanted lines above the first table:

```
Company X           
From    2020-07-13 00:00:00 To  2020-07-16 23:59:00
```

I would like to append all data from all dates for a given ID to its own data frame so that each data frame contains data for just one ID but for all dates.

My plan was to read the whole `.csv` to a dataframe using:

```
df = pd.read_csv("input_data.csv", header=0, skiprows=3)
```

and then use the data frame index for the rest of the manipulation but this returns:

```
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

I believe this is due to the fact that the `.csv` has the ID, Location, Status, From and fields above each data table.

Is there any way I can overcome this, or am I going about it the wrong way in the first place? Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in **data.csv**.
This code creates a dict with dataframes for each ID. If necessary the dtype of columns can be change before creating the dict.

```
import pandas as pd
fname = 'data.csv'
names = ['Date', 'Time', 'Reading', 'Low', 'High']


# read table into one column
df = pd.read_table(fname, header=None, names=['row'])

# extract ID row and propagate through column
df['ID'] = df.apply(lambda x: x if 'ID' in str(x) else None, axis=1)
df.ffill(inplace=True)
df.ID = df.ID.apply(lambda x: x.strip())

# drop unwanted lines
df = df[df.row.apply(lambda x: True if len(str(x).split()) == 5 else False)]

# parse text data into columns 
new_df = df.row.str.split(expand=True)
new_df.rename(columns=dict(zip(range(len(names)), names)), inplace=True)
new_df['ID'] = df.ID

# create a dict of dataframes
dframes = {id: new_df[new_df.ID == id] for id in new_df.ID.drop_duplicates()}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I haven't gotten it to work so far but will see if I can tweak it.